# Genetic algorithm for Traveling Salesman

Tags: python, performance, python-3.x, genetic-algorithm, traveling-salesman

I have implemented a genetic algorithm in python 3 for a programming assignment, and I think all the logic is correct. A friend of mine has also implemented one which carries out similar logic, however his was done in Java. It took his around 5 seconds to complete 5000 iterations, whereas mine is taking nearly four minutes!

I have tried to determine the bottleneck using the Python profiler (as described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8624798/5664775)), but all of them seem to be taking quite long:

[image]

Are there any optimisations I can make which will improve the duration of my program? Here is the code.

```
import sys, math, random, heapq
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from itertools import chain

if sys.version_info < (3, 0):
   sys.exit("""Sorry, requires Python 3.x, not Python 2.x.""")

class Graph:

    def __init__(self, vertices):
        self.vertices = vertices
        self.n = len(vertices)

    def x(self, v):
        return self.vertices[v][0]

    def y(self, v):
        return self.vertices[v][1]

    # Lookup table for distances
    _d_lookup = {}

    def d(self, u, v):
        """Euclidean Metric d_2((x1, y1), (x2, y2))"""

        # Check if the distance was computed before
        if (u, v) in self._d_lookup:
            return self._d_lookup[(u, v)]

        # Otherwise compute it
        _distance = math.sqrt((u[0] - v[0])**2 + (u[1] - v[1])**2)

        # Add to dictionary
        self._d_lookup[(u, v)], self._d_lookup[(v, u)] = _distance, _distance
        return _distance

    def plot(self, tour=None):
        """Plots the cities and superimposes given tour"""

        if tour is None:
            tour = Tour(self, [])

        _vertices = [self.vertices[0]]

        for i in tour.vertices:
            _vertices.append(self.vertices[i])

        _vertices.append(self.vertices[0])

        plt.title("Cost = " + str(tour.cost()))
        plt.plot(*zip(*_vertices), '-r')
        plt.scatter(*zip(*self.vertices), c="b", s=10, marker="s")
        plt.show()


class Tour:

    def __init__(self, g, vertices = None):
        """Generate random tour in given graph g"""

        self.g = g

        if vertices is None:
            self.vertices = list(range(1, g.n))
            random.shuffle(self.vertices)
        else:
            self.vertices = vertices

        self.__cost = None

    def cost(self):
        """Return total edge-cost of tour"""

        if self.__cost is None:
            self.__cost = 0
            for i, j in zip([0] + self.vertices, self.vertices + [0]):
                self.__cost += self.g.d(self.g.vertices[i], self.g.vertices[j])
        return self.__cost


class GeneticAlgorithm:

    def __init__(self, g, population_size, k=5, elite_mating_rate=0.5,
                 mutation_rate=0.015, mutation_swap_rate=0.2):
        """Initialises algorithm parameters"""

        self.g = g

        self.population = []
        for _ in range(population_size):
            self.population.append(Tour(g))

        self.population_size = population_size
        self.k = k
        self.elite_mating_rate = elite_mating_rate
        self.mutation_rate = mutation_rate
        self.mutation_swap_rate = mutation_swap_rate

    def crossover(self, mum, dad):
        """Implements ordered crossover"""

        size = len(mum.vertices)

        # Choose random start/end position for crossover
        alice, bob = [-1] * size, [-1] * size
        start, end = sorted([random.randrange(size) for _ in range(2)])

        # Replicate mum's sequence for alice, dad's sequence for bob
        for i in range(start, end + 1):
            alice[i] = mum.vertices[i]
            bob[i] = dad.vertices[i]

        # Fill the remaining position with the other parents' entries
        current_dad_position, current_mum_position = 0, 0

        for i in chain(range(start), range(end + 1, size)):

            while dad.vertices[current_dad_position] in alice:
                current_dad_position += 1

            while mum.vertices[current_mum_position] in bob:
                current_mum_position += 1

            alice[i] = dad.vertices[current_dad_position]
            bob[i] = mum.vertices[current_mum_position]

        # Return twins
        return Tour(self.g, alice), Tour(self.g, bob)

    def mutate(self, tour):
        """Randomly swaps pairs of cities in a given tour according to mutation rate"""

        # Decide whether to mutate
        if random.random() < self.mutation_rate:

            # For each vertex
            for i in range(len(tour.vertices)):

                # Randomly decide whether to swap
                if random.random() < self.mutation_swap_rate:

                    # Randomly choose other city position
                    j = random.randrange(len(tour.vertices))

                    # Swap
                    tour.vertices[i], tour.vertices[j] = tour.vertices[j], tour.vertices[i]

    def select_parent(self, k):
        """Implements k-tournament selection to choose parents"""
        tournament = random.sample(self.population, k)
        return max(tournament, key=lambda t: t.cost())

    def evolve(self):
        """Executes one iteration of the genetic algorithm to obtain a new generation"""

        new_population = []

        for _ in range(self.population_size):

            # K-tournament for parents
            mum, dad = self.select_parent(self.k), self.select_parent(self.k)
            alice, bob = self.crossover(mum, dad)

            # Mate in an elite fashion according to the elitism_rate
            if random.random() < self.elite_mating_rate:
                if alice.cost() < mum.cost() or alice.cost() < dad.cost():
                    new_population.append(alice)
                if bob.cost() < mum.cost() or bob.cost() < dad.cost():
                    new_population.append(bob)

            else:
                self.mutate(alice)
                self.mutate(bob)
                new_population += [alice, bob]

        # Add new population to old
        self.population += new_population

        # Retain fittest
        self.population = heapq.nsmallest(self.population_size, self.population, key=lambda t: t.cost())


    def run(self, iterations=5000):
        for _ in range(iterations):
            self.evolve()

    def best(self):
        return max(self.population, key=lambda t: t.cost())


# Test on berlin52: http://elib.zib.de/pub/mp-testdata/tsp/tsplib/tsp/berlin52.tsp
g = Graph([(565.0, 575.0), (25.0, 185.0), (345.0, 750.0), (945.0, 685.0), 
           (845.0, 655.0), (880.0, 660.0), (25.0, 230.0), (525.0, 1000.0), 
           (580.0, 1175.0), (650.0, 1130.0), (1605.0, 620.0), (1220.0, 580.0), 
           (1465.0, 200.0), (1530.0, 5.0), (845.0, 680.0), (725.0, 370.0), 
           (145.0, 665.0), (415.0, 635.0), (510.0, 875.0), (560.0, 365.0), 
           (300.0, 465.0), (520.0, 585.0), (480.0, 415.0), (835.0, 625.0), 
           (975.0, 580.0), (1215.0, 245.0), (1320.0, 315.0), (1250.0, 400.0), 
           (660.0, 180.0), (410.0, 250.0), (420.0, 555.0), (575.0, 665.0), 
           (1150.0, 1160.0), (700.0, 580.0), (685.0, 595.0), (685.0, 610.0), 
           (770.0, 610.0), (795.0, 645.0), (720.0, 635.0), (760.0, 650.0), 
           (475.0, 960.0), (95.0, 260.0), (875.0, 920.0), (700.0, 500.0), 
           (555.0, 815.0), (830.0, 485.0), (1170.0, 65.0), (830.0, 610.0), 
           (605.0, 625.0), (595.0, 360.0), (1340.0, 725.0), (1740.0, 245.0)])

ga = GeneticAlgorithm(g, 100)
ga.run()

best_tour = ga.best()
g.plot(best_tour)
```

Comment: This is an excellent first question, welcome on CodeReview! :)

Comment: @TopinFrassi Thank you! It gives friendlier vibes than StackOverflow.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ```
>     def x(self, v):
>         return self.vertices[v][0]
>
>     def y(self, v):
>         return self.vertices[v][1]
> ```

I think these two methods are dead code and could be deleted.

---

> ```
>     # Lookup table for distances
>     _d_lookup = {}
>
>     def d(self, u, v):
>         """Euclidean Metric d_2((x1, y1), (x2, y2))"""
>
>         # Check if the distance was computed before
>         if (u, v) in self._d_lookup:
>             return self._d_lookup[(u, v)]
>
>         # Otherwise compute it
>         _distance = math.sqrt((u[0] - v[0])**2 + (u[1] - v[1])**2)
>
>         # Add to dictionary
>         self._d_lookup[(u, v)], self._d_lookup[(v, u)] = _distance, _distance
>         return _distance
> ```

Would be good to have better documentation: what's the relationship between `u` and `(x1, y1)`?

In my testing, the lookup didn't actually provide any speedup. I think this is mainly because it's such a big key. If I change `u` and `v` to be indices into `self.vertices`, there is a speed saving. Obviously this also means changing `Tour.cost`, which is the only method which calls `Graph.d`.

---

> ```
>         if vertices is None:
>             self.vertices = list(range(1, g.n))
>             random.shuffle(self.vertices)
>         else:
>             self.vertices = vertices
> ```

I had to reverse engineer from the `if` case what the meaning of `vertices` is. A comment explaining it would have been helpful.

---

> ```
>     def cost(self):
>         """Return total edge-cost of tour"""
>
>         if self.__cost is None:
>             self.__cost = 0
>             for i, j in zip([0] + self.vertices, self.vertices + [0]):
>                 self.__cost += self.g.d(self.g.vertices[i], self.g.vertices[j])
> ```

[Yakym](//codereview.stackexchange.com/users/100674/yakym-pirozhenko)'s proposed code change was buggy (although it's now fixed), but the point about avoiding creating new lists is a good one. An alternative way of fixing Yakym's code which takes into account the goal of avoiding list creation and is further adapted to correspond to my point about using indices as arguments to `Graph.d` is

```
            self.__cost = self.g.d(0, self.vertices[0]) + \
                          sum(map(self.g.d, self.vertices, self.vertices[1:])) + \
                          self.g.d(self.vertices[-1], 0)
```

---

Separate point on cost: since you're always going to call `cost()` (if nothing else then in the `heapq` selection), is there any benefit to making it lazy?

---

> ```
>     def crossover(self, mum, dad):
>         """Implements ordered crossover"""
>
>         size = len(mum.vertices)
> ```

Why not this?

```
        size = g.n - 1
```

---

> ```
>         # Choose random start/end position for crossover
>         alice, bob = [-1] * size, [-1] * size
>         start, end = sorted([random.randrange(size) for _ in range(2)])
>
>         # Replicate mum's sequence for alice, dad's sequence for bob
>         for i in range(start, end + 1):
>             alice[i] = mum.vertices[i]
>             bob[i] = dad.vertices[i]
>
>         # Fill the remaining position with the other parents' entries
>         current_dad_position, current_mum_position = 0, 0
>
>         for i in chain(range(start), range(end + 1, size)):
>
>             while dad.vertices[current_dad_position] in alice:
>                 current_dad_position += 1
>
>             while mum.vertices[current_mum_position] in bob:
>                 current_mum_position += 1
>
>             alice[i] = dad.vertices[current_dad_position]
>             bob[i] = mum.vertices[current_mum_position]
> ```

Here we have a familiar culprit when code runs too slow: `in list`. Testing whether a list contains a value takes linear time: if you want a fast `in` test, use a `set`:

```
        skipalice, skipbob = set(alice), set(bob)
        for i in chain(range(start), range(end + 1, size)):

            while dad.vertices[current_dad_position] in skipalice:
                current_dad_position += 1

            while mum.vertices[current_mum_position] in skipbob:
                current_mum_position += 1

            alice[i] = dad.vertices[current_dad_position]
            bob[i] = mum.vertices[current_mum_position]
            current_dad_position += 1
            current_mum_position += 1
```

But actually a faster approach seems to be to use a comprehension and advanced indexing:

```
    def crossover(self, mum, dad):
        """Implements ordered crossover"""

        size = g.n - 1

        # Choose random start/end position for crossover
        start, end = sorted([random.randrange(size) for _ in range(2)])

        # Identify the elements from mum's sequence which end up in alice,
        # and from dad's which end up in bob    
        mumxo = set(mum.vertices[start:end+1])
        dadxo = set(dad.vertices[start:end+1])

        # Take the other elements in their original order
        alice = [i for i in dad.vertices if not i in mumxo]
        bob = [i for i in mum.vertices if not i in dadxo]

        # Insert selected elements of mum's sequence for alice, dad's for bob
        alice[start:start] = mum.vertices[start:end+1]
        bob[start:start] = dad.vertices[start:end+1]

        # Return twins
        return Tour(self.g, alice), Tour(self.g, bob)
```

---

> ```
>     def mutate(self, tour):
> ```

I get a moderate speedup by pulling out `n = len(tour.vertices)`, saving up to \$n^2\$ calls of `len`.

---

> ```
>     def select_parent(self, k):
>         """Implements k-tournament selection to choose parents"""
>         tournament = random.sample(self.population, k)
>         return max(tournament, key=lambda t: t.cost())
> ```

I haven't tried this, but I wonder whether it might be faster to sort `self.population` and then sample from `range(self.population_size)`.

---

> ```
>         # Retain fittest
>         self.population = heapq.nsmallest(self.population_size, self.population, key=lambda t: t.cost())
> ```

The documentation for `heapq.nsmallest` says

> [It performs] best for smaller values of n. For larger values, it is more efficient to use the sorted() function.

Here `n` is `len(self.population)/2`, and I see a small speedup from

```
        self.population = sorted(self.population, key=lambda t: t.cost())[0:self.population_size]
```

It might be worth going for a linear quickselect approach instead.

Comment: NB I've been doing performance testing on the smaller test case http://elib.zib.de/pub/mp-testdata/tsp/tsplib/tsp/burma14.tsp because I was using an online code execution environment with a 60-second time limit; but on that test case the changes mentioned above got the runtime down from 40 seconds to 28 seconds.

Comment: Thank you very much for all these! I'll be sure to read through them soon and give you feedback.

Comment: Thank you very much for all your optimisations, I have implemented all of them, together with some others (such as replacing the cost lookup table with an numpy matrix). Unfortunately however, I still haven't managed to decrease runtime to under a minute (you said it took you 28 seconds). Is there something I'm missing here? This is the updated code with all changes: https://ideone.com/oedbmG.

Comment: You're probably missing the part where that 28 seconds was for a 14-city tour, not a 52-city one.

Comment: Oh right, sorry about that. Is it normal for such algorithms to take this long though? Like I said, my friend managed to compile in around 5 seconds in Java.

Comment: Without your friend's Java code to compare, it's hard to know whether it's due to differences in the approach or differences in the VM / library implementation. In general, Python is higher level than Java, so the code is usually shorter and easier to read but slower. But a factor of more than one order of magnitude makes me wonder whether your friend's code is doing something different.

Comment: I believe he implemented a different type of crossover: sequential constructive crossover operator (SCX)

Comment: But according to the python profiler which I've run again, it seems that the distance function `d` is taking up the largest chuck of runtime (271s out of 545s), the second being the built-in `sum()` function (62s out of 545s). Can anything be done about this?

Answer (score 1):

An extended comment rather than an answer. You can optimize the cost function as follows:

```
def cost(self):
    """Return total edge-cost of tour"""
    if self.__cost is None:
        pts = [self.g.vertices[i] for i in self.vertices]
        pts.append(self.g.vertices[0])
        self.__cost = sum(map(g.d, pts, pts[1:])) + g.d(pts[0], pts[-1])
    return self.__cost
```

First, you avoid looking up each point in `g.vertices` twice. More importantly, each of `[0] + self.vertices` and `self.vertices + [0]` creates a new list, necessarily making a copy of `self.vertices`. This shaves of about 15% of runtime on my machine.

Comment: Also, this introduces a bug. The original code uses `[0] + self.vertices` and `self.vertices + [0]` because `0` is not in `self.vertices`, but does need to be taken into account in the tour.

Comment: @PeterTaylor `dist` I think is referring to `graph.d`, the metric function. And as you rightly pointed out, the `[0]` is excluded for uniqueness of representation (otherwise tours can have multiple representations: each tour is assumed to start from zero)

Comment: @LukeCollins you are right, I was referring to `graph.d`. Also, since computing Euclidean distance is pretty cheap, memoizing the distances does save much. It ended up being only a tiny bit faster than recomputing the distance each time.

Comment: @PeterTaylor absolutely right, I missed the point about `0` being present in every tour.

Comment: Given that the point is to save list creation, IMO a better fix is the one I've given in my answer; although reducing from two list creations to one is an improvement. @LukeCollins, for true uniqueness of representation you should enforce `t.vertices[0] <= t.vertices[-1]` for a tour, since following the tour backwards doesn't fundamentally change it.